# AngularJS: Latency to binding variable after REST

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, font-awesome

I have a REST service and my idea is to use a variable that indicates if the REST service is loading or not.

**Controller**

```
  $scope.loading = true;

  $http.get('/Something').
            success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.loading = false;
                //Something 
            }).
            error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
               //Something
            });
```

**View**

```
    {{loading}}

    //Font Awesome loading icon
    <div data-ng-hide="!loading" class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-2x"></div>
```

The result of {{loading}} is immediately, but the "data-ng-hide" takes a few seconds more to hide it. I don't understand what happen and how to solve this problem.

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any animations set up for ng-hide? see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide. Maybe some hide animation is taking a few seconds before actualy hide your loading component?

Comment: oooh! Thanks. I don't have animations but just I tried this after your comment and works:
        <div data-ng-hide="!loading" >
            <span class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-2x"></span>
        </div>
I think the problem is for Font Awesome in the same tag to ng-hide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is for Font Awesome in the same tag to ng-hide...

This works:

```
     <div data-ng-hide="!loading" >
        <span class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-2x"></span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Aral font Awesome could be a viable issue. Also u can use ng-clock (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak) if you want to delay the loading and hence wait for all the components to load. Hope this helps. Cheers